# EvtSubscribe doesn't work with query on EventRecordID

Tags: windows, event-log, msdn

I'm trying to subscribe on upcoming events using function `EvtSubscribe`:

```
hsubscription = microsoft_EvtSubscribe(
    NULL,                          // session
    NULL,                          // signal
    NULL,                          // channel path
    L"<QueryList><Query Id="0" Path='Application'><Select>*[System[EventRecordID >= 1037374]]</Select></Query></QueryList>" // query
    NULL,                          // bookmark
    context,                       // context
    clbk,                          // callback
    EvtSubscribeToFutureEvents     // flags
);
```

But the callback has never been called back.
I tried several approaches using XPath + channel path: `Event/System[EventRecordID=1037374]`, `*[System/EventRecordID=1037374]`, but it doesn't work neither.
BTW, whenever the subscription is created for any other field (like: `*[System/Computer="windows-build"]`) everything works perfectly fine.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: c != c++, and it's not about the incorrect expression that it represents, it's about the programming languages, they are not the same.

Comment: Did you make sure that you have events in Application channel with EventRecordID >= 1037374? Or, maybe you want to get the events where EventID >= 1037374 instead of EventRecordID?

Comment: @n0p nope, there's no events with given ID and that's the reason to create a subscription - I need the callback to be called once they arrived. Yes, I need EventRecordID, not EventID.